# firefox web extension tutorial: script repeat itself

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon

I've followed the following guide to train myself at firefox addon:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Your_second_WebExtension

Then I started tweaking the code to add my own functions, keeping the same architecture/logic.

But then I noticed that my functions, when launched by clicking in the menu, execute sereval times, actually the number of times I've clicked in the addon menu since I loaded the page.

example: I created a menu option called Repeat Test that links to a function called "Repeat Test" that is just console.log('1');
- first click, I get 1
- second click, I get 1 / 1
- third click, I get 1 / 1 / 1

where can that come from ?

my code:

beast.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="choose_beast.css"/>
  </head>

  <body>

<div class="beast">Remove Model Map</div>
<div class="beast">Color Formulas</div>
<div class="beast">Image Overlay</div>
<div class="beast">Repeat Test</div>

<script src="choose_beast.js"></script>
  </body>

</html>
```

choose_beast.js:

```
   function optionSelection(myvar) {

  switch (myvar) {
    case "Remove Model Map":
      return "modelMap";
    case "Color Formulas":
      return "colorFormulas";
    case "Image Overlay":
        return "imageOverlay";
    case "Repeat Test":
      return "repeatTest";
  }
}

document.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  if (!e.target.classList.contains("beast")) {
    return;
  }

  var clickedOption = e.target.textContent;
  var optionActivated = optionSelection(clickedOption);

  chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {
    file: "/content_scripts/beastify.js"
  });

  chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs) {
    chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, {option: optionActivated});


  });


});
```

and finally, beastify.js:

```
function myaddon(request, sender, sendResponse) {

  switch (request.option){
    case "modelMap": removeModelMap();
    case "colorFormulas" : colorFormulas();
    case "imageOverlay" : overlay();
    case "repeatTest" : repeatTest();
  }

}

function repeatTest()
{
  console.log('1');
}

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(myaddon);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the issue here. this code

```
chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {
    file: "/content_scripts/beastify.js"
  });
```

is contained into the click event manager, so every time you click, the script is executed, which adds to the fact that later on a message is sent to the script every time a click is made.

I don't know if this is a mistake or not (it's actually like this on the mozilla website):
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Your_second_WebExtension

but it was quite annoying for me. I'll notify them.